# CSS: How can I make the display 1, 2, or 4 columns but never 3 columns?

Tags: html, css

How can I use css to make sure the following code can display as 1, 2, or 4 columns but never as 3 columns?

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.panel {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 3px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: wrap each two element inside a div and apply another flexbox layout there

Comment: Thanks Temani. This really did a great job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's all about the width since you are using `flex-box`. if you want an item to take the entire row give the container `width` of `100%` and if you want 2 items next to each other give it `width:50%` if you want 4 items then make sure to give it `25%` of the width.

I made this responsive example I used the names bootstrap uses to make it easier to understand in case you are using bootstrap.

Note that you should work inside the `div` with class `wrap`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  outline: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.panel {
  height: 100px;
  outline: 2px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  background-color: green;
}

.wrap {
  margin: 0 1rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  color: white;
}

.col-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-mid-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-xl-4 {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel col-12 col-mid-6 col-xl-4">
    <div class="wrap">div1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel col-12 col-mid-6 col-xl-4">
    <div class="wrap">div2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel col-12 col-mid-6 col-xl-4">
    <div class="wrap">div3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel col-12 col-mid-6 col-xl-4">
    <div class="wrap">div4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if that didn't help let me know.

Comment: This is a great example, but what I'm looking for is the ability for the flex container to be either 1, 2, or 4 elements on flex expansion but never 3. Thank you so much for your hard work.

Comment: Great all you need is to remove the class that you don't want to keep it fix.

Say that you only want 4 items next to each other. Simple just keep the class `col-xl-4` and remove the `col-12 `and `col-mid-6` you will end up with 4 fixed items next to each other.

Comment: I don't know too much about bootstrap, but it looks like you are using a bootstrap solution. While I have seen great stuff using bootstrap, I'm doing this as minimalistic as possible to make sure I can explain how it works. Which means no bootstrap.

Comment: I'm not using bootstrap in this example. That's pure CSS. Anyway in order to help out. I need a screenshot of the desired output.

Comment: Ah, sorry, no scrollbars on my phone. You are right, you've defined your classes. This looks promising.

Comment: Ah you're the best. This is fantastic work and solves most of my css problems. I hope you have a great day, my friend.

Comment: glad to help. buddy